# multiple focused elements in the browser

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to have multiple elements (such as input elements) focused in the browser.

I would like to reproduce the effect of Sublime Text 2.

Comment: No, there is not. What exactly are you trying to do (effect of ST2)?

Comment: Focusing on something means that it's the only one getting attention. Let's say you have two textboxes focused - will writing write in both? How about a scrollable element and an unscrollable element. What will scrolling do? You need to better define what focusing on several elements means.

Comment: @Zirak: I want to focus two input elements. And yes, writing will write in both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible.

Check out this test:

```
$('#one').focus(function(){
    $('#one, #two').focus();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/epBea/

**EDIT**

If you wanted both fields to *look like* they had focus, you could fake this by adding `divs` around the `inputs` and styling with a `border` on `focus`.

```
$('#one').focus(function(){
    $('#one, #two').parent().css('border','1px solid red');
});
```

You also need to remove the `outline` for each input in the css.

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/epBea/1/

**Warning:** I think this is a bad usability idea, as focus is meant to tell people which field they are working in.

Comment: What's this demo supposed to do? If I click on `#one` then...`#one` remains focussed?

Comment: Exactly @DavidThomas.  If you could have two inputs focused, both would gain focus.